# Does 1440p monitor has any significant advantage over 1080p for gaming and live streaming?

Tags: monitors, displays

I'm trying to decide between 1080p and 1440p Montor to buy for gaming and streaming on online streaming platforms like twitch , YouTube etc. Does 1440p monitor have any significant advantage over 1080p for gaming and live streaming? If it helps, I play/stream mostly league of legends and mmos like black desert online, lost ark etc. All those esport tournaments of leagoue of legends mostly happen on 1440p or 1080p monitor? Most game streamers/ esport professionals play games on 1080p or 1440p monitor? I sit very close to my PC and my eyesight is pretty good. What is the current esport norm - 1080p or 1440p?